# Main site changed look, but only in one device

Tags: support, user-interface

Using Firefox on an iPad, suddenly the view for the main site changed; it now looks as follows:
[image]

The meta site looks the same as it always has, and when I go to the site using firefox on a different device, it also looks as usual. Anyone know what I did and how to undo it?

Comment: Didn't you simply switch to mobile web by mistake? You can choose between full site and mobile version. When in mobile version, scroll to bottom and choose "full site". Here is a screenshot of the bottom bar in the mobile version: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqQht.png

Comment: @MartinSleziak That did it! Thanks; still getting used to the iPad....

Comment: I've found that the cookies expire and cause the mobile web version to reappear. You didn't necessarily do anything to switch and since the cookies are set per-device, that's why it only happened in one place.

Comment: @Catija: Thank you; I’m pretty sure I “clicked” on something by accident, causing the change. Selecting “full site” as Martin Sleziak suggested has fixed it.

Comment: Note that in the top-left there is an incognito mode icon, so in this case the culprit is definitely not an expired cookie.

Comment: @Catija: I kinda wish there was a global server-side setting to disable mobile and responsive interfaces globally. I hate it that I have to do it for each site separately every time...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you simply switched to mobile web by mistake. It is possible to switch between mobile version and full site, currently you can find the switch near the bottom of the page.

In the mobile version, you should click on "full site" to change the interface. When on full site, you can get to mobile version by clicking on "mobile".

Here is a screenshot of the bottom bar from the mobile version:

[image: screenshot]

And this is where to switch to mobile if you are displaying full site:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I have posted this so that the question does not remain unanswered. I should add a caveat that I do not use MO on any mobile devices - so users who have more experience with them might be able to say more about this.